# Is the result of a matrix transformation equivalent to the that of that same matrix but orthonormalized?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Now, what I understand is that one performs this Gram-Schmidt process to orthonormalize a given transformation matrix, which yields many computational advantages. However, I'm not sure about the implications the orthonormalization has on the result of the transformation. I will attempt to express my question more formally.

Say we have the transformation matrix $A$ of full rank such that $A^{-1} \neq A^t,$ i.e., the matrix $A$ consists of linearly independent vectors which aren't orthogonal to each other, a vector $v,$ and the orthonormalized transformation matrix $A'.$ Is it true that $Av = A'v?$ And if not, is this unimportant? What am I missing?

Comment: First, let's clear up some questions of notation. What is meant by "A-1=/ AT" and "AV=A!V?"

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't make myself clear! A-1 as in the inverse of A and AT as in the transposed A.

AV is in the vector-matrix multiplication product of V and A and A!V as in the product of A! (the orthonormalised) and V.

Comment: Originally, you did not assume that $A$ is full rank; however, in order to talk about $A^{-1},$ we need that $A$ is a square matrix (i.e., $A$ is the matrix associated to the transformation $T : V \to V$) and that $A$ is full rank (since $T$ is invertible if and only if $T$ is injective if and only if $T$ is surjective). I have edited your post to reflect these observations.

Comment: Before I proceed with addressing your main question, I want to make sure that I haven't fundamentally altered anything.

Comment: Thank you very much for editing my question! No, you haven't altered my questions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the key features of the Gram-Schmidt process is that the vectors generated by it span the same $k$-vector subspace as the original vectors. Put into the language of matrices, this means that the column space of $A$ (or the range of $T$) is the same as the column space of $A'$ (or the range of $T'$). (Here, I assume that the linearly independent vectors we started with were the columns of $A.$) Consequently, we have that $$\{w \in V \,|\, T(v) = w \text{ for some } v \in V\} = \{w \in V \,|\, T'(v) = w \text{ for some } v \in V\}.$$ But that does not imply that $Av = T(v) = T'(v) = A'v$ for all $v \in V.$

For instance, consider the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R^2,$ i.e., the set of column vectors $(a, b)^t$ for $a, b \in \mathbb R.$ Observe that the vectors $v = (1, 1)^t$ and $w = (1, 2)^t$ are linearly independent (because the matrix with columns $v$ and $w$ has determinant 1). By Gram-Schmidt, we obtain an orthogonal basis $v_1 = (1, 1)^t$ and $v_2 = (-\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2)^t,$ and we can convert this into an orthonormal basis by taking $v' = \frac{v_1}{||v_1||}$ and $w' = \frac{v_2}{||v_2||}.$

Using these as columns, we can form the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A'.$ We will denote by $e_1 = (1, 0)$ and $e_2 = (0, 1)$ the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^2.$ Observe that we have $$A e_1 = v \neq \frac{v_1}{||v_1||} = v' = A' e_1,$$ and the analogous statement holds for $e_2$ in place of $e_1.$

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Do we then account for this fact (that the orthonormalized matrix probably yields different results from the original transformation matrix) after the transformation or try to quantify the magnitude of the difference in some way? I'm trying to connect this with the process of changing to the eigenbasis when we want to take a matrix to the nth power. In this process we "convert" the matrix back to its original basis after taking the diagonal matrix to the nth power.

Comment: I believe that you are referring to the fact that a matrix $A$ (or a linear operator) is diagonalizable if and only if there exists an ordered basis $\mathscr B$ (of eigenvectors) such that $A = PDP^{-1},$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix whose nonzero entries are the eigenvalues of $A$ (corresponding to the appropriate eigenvector) and $P$ is the matrix whose columns are the vectors of $\mathscr B$ (i.e., the eigenvectors of $A$).

Comment: Is it correct that your question is essentially, "Is there a similar result for the matrix obtained from the Gram-Schmidt process?"

Comment: Generally, there exists such a thing called the "change of basis" matrix  that allows us to write a vector  in one basis ℬ as a new vector  in another basis ℬ′. One important feature of the change of basis matrix  is that its inverses is the change of basis matrix  that converts a vector in the new basis ℬ′ to a vector in the old basis ℬ. Consequently, we have that '=, where  is the change of basis matrix from the Gram-Schmidt basis and  is the change of basis matrix from the Gram-Schmidt basis to the original basis.

Comment: You last comment was a bit over my head. :D I'm afraid I again failed to make clear my question. These are all new concepts for me and they're still somewhat foggy in my head. I'll try again, say we want to know the effect of a transformation matrix A on a vector V but don't want to go through the trouble of applying the transformation directly, but rather orthonormalize the matrix first, and then execute the transformation using the orthonormalized matrix. cont. in next comment

Comment: Knowing this orthonormalized matrix probably results in a different vector than if we applied the original transformation matrix directly, do we try to account for this fact? I only mentioned transforming to the eigenbasis as an example where, after converting our transformation matrix (for example A raised to the 4th power, A^4 applied to a vector) to a form where we facilitate raising it to the 4th power (its diagonal form), we convert it back afterwards, thus ensuring that we obtain the same result from the transformation matrix as we would have if we directly applied A^4 to the vector.

Comment: I also have a background in analysing data. Usually when we implement some method to estimate certain parameters, we try to also estimate to what degree these parameters deviate from the true parameters. So I'm wondering if in the case of the Gram-Schmidt process, or in linear algebra in general, one tries to quantify the effects of these "computational shortcuts". If you my line of thinking completely nonsensical, I fully understand, since, like I said, I'm just now diving into the world of "higher" mathematics and I still have a lot to learn. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: I feel like your question could be better answered by someone who studies numerical analysis. In my line of research, we are not too concerned with error analysis; we just use these tools to study the bigger picture. But for the sake of trying, I checked Wikipedia, and it seems that applying Gram-Schmidt in this way is "inherently numerically unstable." Here is the link for reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Computing_the_QR_decomposition. See also the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#Numerical_stability.